# API trouble with jQuery / AJAX

Tags: ajax, api, jquery

This is my second day with jQuery & AJAX. I've done as much googleing as I know to do for this. But, with not knowing what I'm looking for, I'm lost. This is very close to working, but I can't quite figure it out.

I'm trying to use my company's ("xyz") API, and it won't work when I have the form action = a url to the page.

I've done this many times in PHP. The APIs URL is:

```
xyz.com/getdata.php?from=tt&isbn={variable_int}
```

Can someone give me a hand?

```
<form method="post" action="xyz.com/getdata.php" id="searchForm">
    <input type="text" name="isbn" placeholder="Search..." />
    <input class="myaccount" id="doSearch" name="doSearch" type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

<div id="result"></div>

{literal}
<script>
  // attach a submit handler to the form
  $("#searchForm").submit(function(event) {

    // stop form from submitting normally
    event.preventDefault(); 

    // get some values from elements on the page:
    var $form = $( this ),
       term = $form.find( 'input[name="isbn"]' ).val(),
       url = $form.attr( 'action' );

    // Send the data using post and put the results in a div
//    $.post( url, { doSearch: "Search", isbn: term } ,
    $.post( url, { from: "tt", isbn: term } ,
    function( data ) {
          var content = $( data );
          $( "#result" ).html( content );
      }
    );
  });
</script>
```

Thanks so much (in advance)!

Comment: Is the page running this script on the xyz.com domain? If not, browser security rules will prevent you from POSTing information to the xyz.com domain.

Comment: probably because you are running your code on localhost and the you are posting your ur ajax request on company's url. Are you doing this. If yes then you are making cross domain request. use $.ajax nad dataType=jsonp

Comment: Yes. It's running on different domain. "$.ajax and dataType=jsonp" will be a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Cross-domain with an AJAX request is not as easy as it seems.

Here's an interesting link you should read: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but if you use the string below

> xyz.com/getdata.php?from=tt&isbn={variable_int}

the method to send data is "get". The form uses the method "post". I think there is a conflict.